# Is showing that $x_n \rightarrow x_0\Rightarrow f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ for a single sequence enough to prove continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For all my homework in real analysis, when I've been asked to show that a function is continuous, I just found a single $x_n \in D$ and showed that when $x_n \rightarrow x_0$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$. Apparently, the sequence definition (as opposed to the epsilon delta definition) is (basically) only used to prove a function is not continuous, and I can't prove a function *is* continuous because then I'd have to show this is true for *all* possible sequences? Am I doing the math wrongly? Should I always use the epsilon delta definition when trying to prove that a function is continuous?

Comment: In a metric space, sequential continuity is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: Yes, but to prove a function is continous, I'd have to prove the sequential continuity for ALL possible sequences right? So would you only use the seq definition to prove a function isn't continuous? I

Comment: You'd just need to show the condition for an arbitrary sequence.

Comment: So if I picked a single sequence in domain $x_n = 1/n$, and showed that as $x_n \rightarrow x_0$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$, this would be incorrect right? as $x_n$ is not arbitrary

Comment: That would be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it must be shown for all possible convergent  sequences.  HW for you: prove that ANY function $f: X \rightarrow Y$,  X nonempty, has a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ with $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$

Comment: oh god. this is not good.

Comment: Yes, picking just that sequence would falsely lead you to conclude the $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(\pi/x)/x & x\ne 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases} $$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: The sequential defintion says that **for all** sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x$, we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. That means that to prove a function is continuous, it is not enough to work with a single sequence, you need to prove that **any** sequence that converges to $x$ will “work.” By contrast, the negation of this is “**there exists** a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x$, but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x)$”. So to prove, using sequences, that a function is **not** continuous, you only need to exhibit a single sequence where things go haywire.

Comment: Basically, if I said “Everyone here is named Todd”, then to prove me wrong it would be enough for someone to stand up and say “My name is Charlie.” But to prove me right, it is not enough for someone to stand up and say “That’s right: my name is Todd.”

Comment: To use the sequential criterion, it is not enough to find $\mathit{one}$ sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$ for which $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$. You have to show that this is the case for an $\mathit{arbitrary}$ sequence converging to $x_0$.

Comment: I guesss I got confused because the definition in our book if $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ whenever $x_n \rightarrow x_0$. Didn't realize this implies for all sequences. So can someone give an example of say, proving $f(x) = x$ is continuous over the Reals? Is the general scheme to pick a specific delta s.t $f(x_n) - f(x_0)$ is less than epsilon?

Comment: @MinYoungKim Think about constant sequences

Comment: Ok, let's show that $f(x) = x$ is continuous. Fix $x_0$ and an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to x_0$. Our goal is to prove that $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. By definition of $f$, we have $f(x_n) = x_n \to x_0 = f(x_0)$.

Comment: and we can assume there is always an arbitrary sequence that converges to any point in R because of sequential compactness?

Comment: You can assume it because you know how to construct one. The constant sequence $x_0$ or the sequence $x_0+\frac{1}{n}$ always converge to $x_0$. To assume existence, you just need to know of 1 example. There might be (and there are) uncountably many more, but you don't really care.

Comment: @MinYoungKim: The key word in the definition you quote is *whenever*, which generally means “for all (things) such that…”, unless some explicit restriction on the things has been previously given.  So written out a bit pedantically, “whenever $x_n \to x_0$” means “for all sequences $x_n$ and points $x_0$ such that $x_n \to x_0$”.

Comment: @MinYoungKim It has nothing to do with sequential compactness. Continuity is defined on many different sets, compact or not. Technically, if there is no sequence converging to $x_0$, then it's vacuously true that the function is continuous there. That is because the implication "$x_n$ converges to $x$ $\implies$ $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$" is never violated, so it is true.

Comment: Cheers, got a 3.8 in the class after getting 2.9 in intro proof class the semester before!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is indeed incorrect. Take for example the function 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1, \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
0, \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This is obviously not a continuous function. However, if you look at its behavior along a sequence of rational points, it would appear to be constant (hence continuous).

Comment: I am baffled by the popularity of my answer.

Comment: I just followed the crowd

Answer (score 12):

Yes, unfortunately proving continuity requires showing for every sequence $x_n$ if $x_n\to x$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$

One specific sequence does not prove continuity.

Answer (score 9):

What everyone said is true. But I'd like to say a few more things. Like what the other commenters wrote, if you want to prove $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, you need to say "Let $x_0 \in D$ and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $D$ that converges to some $x_0$." $(x_n)$ in this proof is an *abstract concept*: it's simply an arbitrary sequence in $D$. It's not anything special or specific, it's just some regular sequence that happens to converge to $x_0$.

From there, you have to use the mathematics of sequences, convergence, properties given to you on the problem to logically walk from the statement "$\lim x_n = x_0$" to "$\lim f(x_n)=f(x_0)$." Remark you can't use the properties of any specific sequence, such as $(x_0+\frac{1}{n})_n$.

You also asked if you should always use $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions. So remember I implied you have to play around with the mathematics of sequences, convergence, etc. for arbitrary sequences. This same goes for $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions. Trying to prove a function is continuous by using an actual specific sequence is like trying to prove a function is continuous by setting $\epsilon=1$ and showing there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<1$ whenever $x \in D$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Like...congrats. You did it for $\epsilon=1$, but you didn't do it for $\epsilon=2$. You didn't do it for $\epsilon>0$. It's just for $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions, the idea of using arbitrary $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s is really obvious compared to the sequence definition. However the idea is still the same: you have to be abstract and arbitrary. I hope this helped.

Comment: It may be helpful to use the term [universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization), which is the name of this rule of inference.

Answer (score 2):

Is not enought find a particular sequence $x_{n}$ such that $x_{n} \to x_{0} \implies f(x_{n}) \to f(x_{0})$
Well, $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ if $ x\in [0,1] $ and $f(x) = 1 $ if $x \in (1,2]$ holds if we take $x_{n} = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ then $x_{n} \to 1$ and $ f(1-\frac{1}{n}) \to f(1)$ but $f$ is not continuos in $x = 1$